# creating draggable text in canvas and/or kinetic

Tags: jquery, canvas, kineticjs

This code successfully draws text on a canvas at the xy coordinates where a mouseclick occurs:

```
function on_canvas_click(ev) {
x = ev.clientX - canvas1.offsetLeft-40;
y = ev.clientY - canvas1.offsetTop;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "blue";
context.font = "bold 16px Arial";
context.fillText([chosenChord], [x], [y]);
}
```

What I want now is that if I click the draw text, I can drag it around the canvas.

One ostensible option would be creating the canvas in kineticjs and then using draggable:true or setDraggable(true), but I cannot figure out how to accomplish the main body of code in kinetic. Alternatively, perhaps there is a means of dragging the text without invoking kinetic.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use double-clicks instead of single-clicks because KineticJS uses mousedown to indicate the start of a drag operation.

You can listen for stage double-clicks and then add draggable text like this:

```
$(stage.getContent()).on('dblclick', function (event) {
    var pos=stage.getMousePosition();
    var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
    var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
    var text=new Kinetic.Text({
        x:mouseX,
        y:mouseY,
        text:"@:"+mouseX+"/"+mouseY,
        fill:"blue",
        draggable:true,
    });
    layer.add(text);
    layer.draw();
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/tLwSM/

[image]